# activity diagram refactoring - shall start with Initial activity?

Tags: uml

My activity diagram would be too big and complex, so I decided to split it into many diagrams. I replaced one branch with another diagram and I linked it into the first diagram, which looks well. I designed the second diagram but I do not know, how to start it.

I think that there must be link to the first diagram. But is it enough or shall there be initial activity (circle) before it? See attached images.

[image: first diagram]
[image: second diagram]

Comment: Why do you not put your pictures on this page? It would be more convenient and stable variant.

Comment: I tried. There is no Attachment feature, so I had to find some online service first. Then I tried to include the image using syntax from help but it did not display. :-(

Comment: But there is an "include picture" button, isn't it?

Comment: Also think about using Interaction overview diagram.

Comment: thx, this option was too obvious to find it :-) I started with reading help unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the contrary, the initial node is excessive on the second diagram. It is already included in the start activity. It is OK to say that the whole activity diagram is an activity in another activity diagram. Look at starting diagram [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html) - a group of activities is concluded in activity frame, as a larger activity.

Also think about using Interaction overview diagram. It is just for showing structured activity diagrams.